# compact surface of revolution

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

I have to prove that a compact surface of revolution is diffeomorphic to a sphere or to a torus. And show that

$\int_{S} K dA=\cases{4\pi&if $S$ is  spherical type 
 \\
   0&if $S$ is toric type}$, where $K$ is the Gauss curvature

Let $S_\alpha$ be a surface of revolution by rotating $\alpha(s)=(f(s),0,h(s))$. Then,
$S_\alpha$ can be parametrized by $\mathbb x(s,\theta)=(f(s)\cos\theta, f(s)\sin\theta, h(s))$

Could you help me please? I don’t even know how to start.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you done the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem yet?

Comment: Hi, can you include the definition for "spherical type" and "toric type", and also the calculation of $K$?

Comment: @Alan I cant use the Gauss-Bonnet theorem

Comment: @John, with spherical type I mean that the surface is diffeomorphic to a sphere and with toric type that it is diffeomorphic to a torus. On the other hand $K$ is the Gauss curvature

Comment: @Trian: Ok, so you can express the surfaces as $x(s, \theta)$, so what is $K(s, \theta)$ in terms of $f$ and $h$?